# nested for loop algorithm simple question (maze printer)

Tags: for-loop, printing, nested, maze

> Why this code is not writing every value in a single line instead of pressing enter every row?

```
     maze=[[".", ".", ".", "."],
           [".", "x", "x", "x"],
           [".", ".", ".", "x"],
           ["x", "x", ".", "."]]


     def print_maze(maze):
         for row in maze:
             row_print = ""
             for value in row:
                 row_print += value + " "
             print(row_print)
print_maze(maze)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using end="" we can print in stright line

```py
maze=[[".", ".", ".", "."],
           [".", "x", "x", "x"],
           [".", ".", ".", "x"],
           ["x", "x", ".", "."]]

for i in range(len(maze)):
    for j in range(len(maze[0])):
        print(maze[i][j], end="")
```

Use this code will help you to print like below

```
  .....xxx...xxx..
```